# Bootstrap class col-md does not split row as it should

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

im trying to split row (col-md-12 = full width of row) for 3 parts - col-md-8 + col-md-2 + col-md-2, but bootstrap class col doesn't work as it shoud and im getting 3x columns sticked 2 each other :(

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<body style="background-color:gray; margin: 0">

  <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 5%; background-color: green;">
    <div>
      <div class="row form-inline">
        <div class="col-md-8" style="display: inline-block">something</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="display: inline-block">something2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="display: inline-block">something3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

What I'm getting:
[image: I'm getting]

What I want to get:
[image: I want get]

PS:
I know that i can use style width 70% + 15% + 15% but i think it s not the point of using bootstrap :/

Comment: Your Code is Ok .This show the output which you want. I use this same code and I get the put that you want.I think you didn'i connect the Bootstrap CDN.

Comment: @Md.AshrafulIslam Thank you for answer, you're right i forgot to add bootstrap... I removed the layout where the bootstrap was added and thought if I get hints bootstrap works :)

Comment: @CuteCodeRob it was problem with missing link to bootstrap, but TY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming based on your screenshot, it looks like your device width is less than **768px**. If that is, therefore it works as expected in your screenshot since you're using `col-md` - [Read more about bootstrap's responsive breakpoints here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

If you do not want to make it responsive, then you should just use `col-{n}`. Read more about [Bootstrap 4 grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

E.g.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h5> Current approach </h5>
<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 5%; background-color: #cfcfcf;">
    <div>
        <div class="row form-inline">
            <div class="col-md-8" style="display: inline-block">col-md-8</div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style="display: inline-block">col-md-2</div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style="display: inline-block">col-md-2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<h5> Expected approach </h5>
<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 5%; background-color: #a0a0a0;">
    <div>
        <div class="row form-inline">
            <div class="col-8" style="display: inline-block">col-8</div>
            <div class="col-2" style="display: inline-block">col-2</div>
            <div class="col-2" style="display: inline-block">col-2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This time it was missing link to bootstrap, that you also added, ty for answer :)

Comment: Ah, that also could be the cause. Glad you figured it out :)